# jQuery link instead of button trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i have this code snippet that opens a modal:

```
<button id="trigger-overlay" class="order">Open Overlay</button>
```

Now, i wanted to include it in Wordpress menu, but i cant add button tag there, so i added:

```
<a href="#" class="order">Open Overlay</a>
```

And i am using jquery to add a ID to that link, like this:

```
$('.order').attr('id','trigger-overlay');
```

ID is added, but link doesnt open anything, aka, it links to "#" instead of opening a modal...
How could i fix this to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you add the ID after the listener is already registered. So it will never open. Can you show us the modal code?

Comment: @eisbehr, here it is http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/js/demo1.js

Comment: When you make sure that `$('.order').attr('id','trigger-overlay');` is called before the `demo1.js`, it should work.

Comment: IS there any reason you can't just add the id in the markup?

Answer (score 0):

This thing may causing due to events binging order. So, your code `$('.order').attr('id','trigger-overlay');` is executing right after click's binding event (I think that event looks like this one: `$('#trigger-overlay').click(function() { ... });`.
If you have ability to change that binding, please use jquery.on method: http://api.jquery.com/on/
So that code will looks like: `$(document).on('click', '#trigger-overlay', function() { ... });`.
Also you can just move `$('.order').attr('id','trigger-overlay');` above the script with that event binding.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your

```
<button id="trigger-overlay" class="order>Open Overlay</button>
```

I'm not sure how you got a modal to trigger, since it is not connected to an event handler like:

```
<button onclick="turnOverlayOn()">Demo Button</button>
```

In this case, there would be a function that targets the overlay/modal and turns its CSS `display` property from `none` to `block` or `inline-block` (however you would like to display it):

```
var turnOverlayOn = function () {
$('targetOverlayId').css('display','block')
}
```

I suggest focusing on attaching an onClick event that triggers a function that does what you want to make the overlay appear.

The function used to turn the overlay off could be:

```
var turnOverlayOff = function () {
$('targetOverlayId').css('display','none')
}
```

You could attach this to a different anchor tag or button to turn the overlay off.

Note: the event should work the same for an anchor tag as it does for a button.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding you want to trigger the button click event. Using the a tag with class order.

try

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.order',function(){
    jQuery('#trigger-overlay').click();
});
```

You can trigger the click event using jquery. Since I have no knowledge of your DOM structure    `jQuery(document).on('click','.order',function()..` will work even if your elements are dynamic (added to the DOM after the script execution) because the click event is bind to the document.

**NOTE:**

When using wordpress always use *jQuery instead of $* to avoid conflicts.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13320003)

Comment: I don`t have enough information to give additional context. I`m only guessing what is the problem and what he is trying to achieve. I will extend the answer though.

Comment: I think that what you added will help future visitors better than simply posting the code by itself.  Thanks :)